# How to create simple http server with boost capable of receiving data editing it and sharing?

Tags: c++, web-services, http, boost, streaming

So using any free opensource cross platform library like boost how to create a web service capable of reciving a data stream (for example stream of mp3 frames) on one URL like `http://adress:port/service1/write/` and capable of sharing latest recived data to all consumers on `http://adress:port/service1/read/` so of course mp3 is just an example of packed stream-able data - generally it can be anything packed. How to create such thing?

Generaly I am honesly triing to understend how to do such thing with [C++ Network Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-netlib/) but it is just quite unclear to me.

Comment: This might be the easiest option: the QHttp class: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qhttp.html.

Comment: Poco (http://pocoproject.org) can be an alternative. It has ready-made HTTP server.

Answer (score 6):

The boost::asio documentation has four examples of complete HTTP server implementations, each with a slightly different threading architecture.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

You do not say what platform to use, but if Windows is an alternative, the Windows HTTP API easy to use and a great performer.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364510(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364510%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You got me - I use windows=) So this one non cross-platform library would generally work for me. but I need an example described above)

Comment: Windows as a host for server software? :o